# Javascript copy function do not work on input type hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tryed to keep `input type=hidden` but it do not copy the value, I need to hide the input field and keep the copy function intact, somebody has a solution?

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copy_link()">copy;<i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
<input  id="my_link" type="text" class="form-control" value="test123 " />
<script>
  function copy_link() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("my_link");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
$('#copy_alert').show();
 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#copy_alert').hide();
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Where is `#copy_alert`?

Comment: It's a button to hide and show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by my self here is the solution:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
  function setClipboard(value) {
    var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
    tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
    tempInput.value = value;
    document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
    tempInput.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
    $('#copy_alert').show();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#copy_alert').hide();
});

</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="setClipboard('copytest')" class="btn btn-light">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function copy_link() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("my_link");
  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $('#copy_alert').show();
  console.log(copyText.value);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#copy_alert').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copy_link()">copy;<i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
<input id="my_link" type="text" class="form-control" value="test123 " />
```

Note:- You have to print variable name with its value in the form of JavaScript. like this
`copyText.value` will resolve your issue

Comment: but sorry the input field should be hidden and it's not working when it's `input type=hidden` or even when `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_link').hide();
});`

Answer (score 1):

do you mean inputmode? If so, inputmode=“none” might be what your looking for. I couldn’t find “hidden” in this article: https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-inputmode/

Comment: no it's not about it but thanks for share